# Android Studio can't open because of invalid because of JVM installation

Tags: java, android-studio, path, jvm

The problem is that when I start Android Studio it shows me this table which says that I haven't installed a valid version of JVM

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljyhQ.png

I have checked the path of JAVA_HOME in my Environment Variables and it is correct

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPYQe.png

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: You need use JDK, not JRE as guys wrote into their answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to `jre` not `jdk`.  Change your `JAVA_HOME` point to valid `JDK`

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of `jre` and also check your `os 64 bit or 32`. and set `jdk` path instead of `jre`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by deleting the jre.Then installer asks to install jre (at installing again). If its not running make a JAVA_HOME variable to this path.